# Handle a repo that has lots of symlinks

Tags: git, symlink

We inherited an application (magento) that has a lot of symlinks (hundreds of directories are symlinks).

When building our repo with git all of these directories are ignored or empty. There is no track of those symlinks.

How can I make git track those symlinks so that when someone clones the repo it has already a functioning application with all symlinks in place?

(I don't want to remove the symlinks and replace them by directories)

Thanks!

Comment: `git add <list of symlinks>; git commit`? What have you tried? `git` tracks symlinks just fine...

Comment: @twalberg thanks. they were all ignored in gitignore. I'm going to close this one